# How to compare doubles in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I have following method which is failing . I think I am comparing double with int but do know the best approach.

```
-(BOOL)isValidCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate
{
   //Always fail first condition here.
    if (coordinate.latitude > -90 && coordinate.latitude< 90) {
        [NSException raise:@"Invalid latitude value" format:@"Latitude of %d is invalid", coordinate.latitude];
    }

    if (coordinate.longitude > -180 && coordinate.longitude < 180) {
        [NSException raise:@"Invalid longitude value" format:@"Longitude of %d is invalid", coordinate.longitude]; 
    }

    [NSException raise:@"Invalid longitude value blash " format:@"Longitude of %d is invalid asd", coordinate.longitude]; 
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: if I have coordinate.latitude of -30.99986 it makes it 3099986 which is greater than -90 and exception is raised.

Comment: well, you raise an exception manually [NSException raise:@"Invalid latitude value" format:@"Latitude of %d is invalid", coordinate.latitude];

Comment: @JavaKaBaby - how do you set the coordinate - let's see that code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comparison should work. The compiler will convert the integer to a floating point number before comparing. If you want to be sure you can change it to:

```
if (coordinate.latitude > -90.0 && coordinate.latitude< 90.0)
```

But your main problem, I think, is that you're *reporting* the wrong numbers. `%d` in a format string tells it to print an *integer*. You need to tell it to output a floating point number:

```
[NSException raise:@"Invalid latitude value" format:@"Latitude of %f is invalid", coordinate.latitude];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate simple question and people were giving me run:) thats exactly right.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in the comparison.

```
if (coordinate.latitude > -90 && coordinate.latitude < 90)
    [NSException raise:@"Invalid latitude value"
                 format:@"Latitude of %d is invalid", coordinate.latitude];
```

*should* raise an exception for -30.99986 by the logic of this code, since it's between -90 and 90. The problem is the `%d` you use to format the error message, which regards its argument as `int` and gives you strange results.

Comment: Thanks a lot +1 have accepted other but you are also right . Appreciate your time honestly.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you don't need to check lat/long explicitly since MapKit has a method that do this to you. Try the following:

```
if (!CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid(coordinate)) {

    [NSException raise:@"Invalid coordinate values" format:@"Latitude: %f Longitude: %f", coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude];
}
```